# Scale illustrator icon to take up the maximum available space

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am creating icons, and all of them should take up as much space as possible in an 256x256 image.

It happens quite often that I do not perfectly meet this requirement when I design the icon.

For example, my icon is only 250 pixels high instead of 256 pixels.
Then I need to manually scale the object up in order to use as much space as possible so that there are no unused pixels.

I would like to ask if there is a way to automatically do this. 
My current workflow is really time-taking.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is a mechanical way to do this, there is a script that resizes an object to the artboard size (which here would be the icon size)

[Fit object to artboard illustrator script](https://gist.github.com/ruandre/7b47cbf2a4c55dac9adb)